# How to show a Activity only once. It should be shown only the app opened at first time.?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to show a Activity only once. It should be shown only when the app is opened at first time. If the user visits 2nd or any other time. The main activity should be displayed.. Ex:- Uc browser... How to do like this .. is there any one help me

Comment: Answered in several related links.  Look at the right side of the page.

Comment: You can store activity related information in shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Create a LaunchActivity that will direct you to either the MainActivity or the ShowOnlyOnceActivity.

Add a SharedPref value, which will be set once the ShowOnlyOnceActivity is shown. Then from the LaunchActivity, if the SharedPref is already set, go straight to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the phone activity you can check a preference SharedPreference in the onCreate. If you need to show another activity instead just route immediately to that activity.

```
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
```

Altenatively, if it is just a message you could show a dialog or do an overlay in the layout of the home page that is only visible on the first use. Again, use the SharedPreference to decide if you have seen the first time page.

Answer (score -2):

See for flags
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
if launched from code.

If launched from xml (manifest), look at 
    android:launchMode="singleTop" (or other value)
from activity tag.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: This OP wants to run code a single time; essentially, they need a way to remember that they've run it. Your answer doesn't make any sense.